# Access the API with HTTP request

Tags: wso2, iot

I am using WSO2 IOT server, RaspberryPi 3 device with LED and DTH11 sensor. I can manage LED with console.

What I am trying to do is turn it **On** and **Off** with my mobile application. So, I want to know how can I send the HTTP request to the API and the request also. The server is running in localhost. Can anyone help me?

This is the command I used:

````
curl -k -X POST https://172.16.13.86:8243/api/device-mgt/v1.0/devices/raspberrypi/operations 
-H 'accept: application/json' -H 'authorization: Bearer a7a156d7-0393-3350-8b9b-0ac956723440' 
-H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"deviceIdentifiers":[r1lovwmwg113],
"operation":{"code":"bulb","type":"CONFIG", "payLoad":"state:ON"}}'```
````

And this is the reply:

> {"activityId":"ACTIVITY_36492","code":"bulb","type":"CONFIG","createdTimeStamp":"Fri
>   Dec 21 11:38:20 IST
>   2018","activityStatus":[{"deviceIdentifier":{"id":"r1lovwmwg113","type":"raspberrypi"},"status":"PENDING"}]}

Comment: Now the server is running on 172.16.13.86. Not in localhost

Comment: You can use alamofire to do api requests from your iPhone https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire